# create objects using factory in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm having trying to create two objects of type **person** using `factory` and on the first try I create the first element and the second attempt instead of creating the second element creates a new element but with the same characteristics as the first element

class `Person`

```
function Person(id, name) {
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
}
```

class `Student extends Person`

```
function Student(id, name) {
  Person.call(this, id, name);
}
```

class `Teacher extends Person`

```
function Teacher(id, name) {
  Person.call(this, id, name);
}
```

using function `factory` to create student and teacher

```
function Factory() {
  this.createPerson = function(type, name) {
    var person;
    var idStudent = 0;
    var idTeacher = 0;

    switch (type) {
      case "1":
        person = new Student(idStudent++, name);
        break;
      case "2":
        person = new Teacher(idTeacher++, name);
        break;
    }
    return person;
  }
}
```

class `School` has an array of person

```
function School(id) {
  this.persons = [];
  this.factory = new Factory();
  this.personCreate = null;

  this.createStudentAndTeacher = function() {
    var type = prompt("Choose ? \n\n[1-Student | 2-Teacher ]");
    var name = prompt("Write name?");

    if (type !== null) {
      this.personCreate = this.factory.createPerson(type,name);
      this.persons.push(this.personCreate);
    } else {
      alert("need to choose");
    }
  }
}
```

created by default

```
var s = new School(1);

var btn = document.createElement('button');
btn.value = "create";
btn.onclick = function(){
  s.createStudentAndTeacher();
}
```

my doubt is when I create the `Student` object with name **"John"**, return **student.id = 0** and **student.name = John** but when I create the new `Student` object with name **"Elisa"**, return the same information **student.id = 0** and **student.name = John** and in fact, should return **student.id = 1** and **student.name = Elisa** and if I create new `Teacher` object with name **"Jerry"**, return the same information **student.id = 0** and **student.name = John** and in fact, should return **teacher.id = 0** and **teacher.name = Jerry**

what I´m doing wrong?

Comment: Are you caching `School`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code has a bug. In the Factory definition, change this

```
function Factory() {
  this.createPerson = function(type, name) {
    var person;
    var idStudent = 0;
    var idTeacher = 0;
```

to this

```
function Factory() {
  var idStudent = 0;
  var idTeacher = 0;
  this.createPerson = function(type, name) {
    var person;
```

then use the console, run these lines.

```
var s = new School();
s.createStudentAndTeacher(); // john
s.createStudentAndTeacher(); // bob
s.persons[0] // id 0:john
s.persons[1] // id 1:bob
```

Comment: I run your code before porting the answer and it worked.

Comment: ok, if I call the `btn.onclick = function(){ s.createStudentAndTeacher(); }` does the same as above

Comment: while debugging try one step at a time. Copy the code you show us here to a new file. Do the changes we propose. Open the console and run my lines. If does not work, try tha same on other browsers. If it works, THEN try to check that code and DIF it with the new one.

Answer (score 2):

Your `createPerson` is redeclaring `idStudent` and `idTeacher` (and resetting them to 0). Try moving that code out of that block.

Comment: I tried to redeclaring `var idStudent` and `var idTeacher` to `this.idSudent` and `this.idTeacher` but still the same